# How to remove default Storybook Canvas styles?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Storybook applies default styles to the the story canvas iframe. This prevents my stories from looking the way they should. How can I get rid of Storybook's default styles?

For example, here is the default style for an `h2` element (via Storybook's page.css):

[image]

The source of that `page.css` is `webpack://src/stories/page.css`.

If I add styles in `preview-head.html`, Storybook will apply my custom styles AND the default Storybook styles, with the default Storybook styles taking precedence (unless my custom style has a strong specificity).

Comment: maybe it will be helpful https://specificity.keegan.st/ (just increase specificity)

Comment: @DaniilLoban thanks, but then I'd have to figure out what all of the defaults are and manually reset them. And if Storybook updates later with more defaults, I'd have to reset them again. Seems very strange for Storybook (a UI preview tool) to not allow us to remove their default styles.

Comment: maybe is it https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/8144  ?

Comment: Thank you @DaniilLoban. I appreciate you looking into that. That github issue is related to resetting the browser default. But on top of the browser default, Storybook applies their own default. I need to remove that and was hoping that Storyboard had a setting where I can do that. I'm already using `material-ui`'s `CssBaseline` (https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/) to reset the browser default but Storybook's default styles are overriding that reset.

Comment: Sorry, @Johnny Oshika, No ideas.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Thank you for your help! I hope someone has an answer to this.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika did you ever figure this out? I"m having the same problem, Storybook flat out breaks a component of mine that works perfectly outside of SB. I want to turn off all SB styles too.

Comment: @Fernando see aedwards22's answer below. It worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default when installing Storybook via `npx sb init` for React, Storybook adds a Page.tsx (.js) file under `src/stories`. In that file they `import './page.css';` simply remove that import and you'll be set.

Hope this is your fix... It may be different depending on what framework you're using.

Comment: This was it! So simple. I'm surprised more people aren't looking for this reset. Many thanks!

Comment: While this works for me, it's odd that Storybook would allow CSS from another module to bleed into other modules where you don't want that style.

Comment: How does this work when I have installed storybook via HTML? It still adds this odd `.css-1p8ieni` to my elements, with their custom styling. How can I remove that?

Comment: I have removed all builtin css and import and still has the .css-* classes

Comment: @jjalonso can you provide a link to a repo?

Comment: Wrote an answer at the end. I got it solved

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MDX Syntax.

I had same issue and it was because I was using MDX Syntax.

When I started using the export syntax it didn't apply any built-in CSS classes.