# How to remove default styles in storybook

Tags: storybook

Similar question but the same: [How to remove default Storybook Canvas styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365461/how-to-remove-default-storybook-canvas-styles)

The default font fam used in Storybook is:

```
font-family: "Nunito Sans", -apple-system, ".SFNSText-Regular", "San Francisco", BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

But this is overriding a lot of my apps fonts as the dont is applied to a class at the element level. See the pic:

[image]

How can this be turned off?

(this is vue with buefy component lib)

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom styling to every different element that storybook renders, in `.storybook/preview.ts`. You can apply an empty style like below (or your own defined style with your own font) and it will not load the custom generated styling.

```
import { styled } from '@storybook/theming';

const divEmpty = styled.div(({ theme }) => ({
}));
const pEmpty = styled.p(({ theme }) => ({
//example of custom font
fontFamily: "Arial"
}));
const spanEmpty = styled.span(({ theme }) => ({
}));
const inputEmpty = styled.input(({ theme }) => ({
}));

export const parameters = {
    ...
    docs: {
        components: {
            p: pEmpty,
            div: divEmpty,
            span: spanEmpty,
            input: inputEmpty
        },
    },
}
```